# flexslider Image Slider: Paragraph text not showing on first slide only

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I'm building a site that's using flexslider for the home page image slider.

It's working well, but when testing in IE7 the paragraph text of the first slide doesn't appear. This is really strange as the h2 and the button are appearing, as are the full contents of all following slides.

I think it's an issue being caused by flexslider, but I'm not sure on how to fix it.

Here's a link to the site: https://mariaridge.myshopify.com/

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

I just shifted the first frame to start from, and now it works:

```
this.dom.find('.flexslider').flexslider({
// your options
startAt: -1
});
```

With a positive number it doesn't work, but with this hack it starts correctly